# why admin grid not showing in front end in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, frontend, uicomponent

i'm working on overriding admin ui filter in custom module

https://belvg.com/blog/ui-grid-component-on-the-front-end-in-magento-2.html
with referring this blog

> but only loading css files not loading Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider

i added with all the steps 
with (ui component)
but not showing anything in front end

**ui component/mpquotesystem_seller_filters.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        <item name="update_url" path="mpquotesystem/sellerquote/filters" xsi:type="url"/>
        </item>

    </argument>

</listing>
```

can you help me to find out the problem??

Comment: it will be great if you can show your code :)

Comment: updated..........

Comment: This peace of code won't show any grid. Didn't you do anything more yet?

Comment: i followed this blog  https://belvg.com/blog/ui-grid-component-on-the-front-end-in-magento-2.html

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-list-with-pager-in-frontend/  refer this it might help you @prabhakaran7

Comment: not need this 
i need  filter (like back end )
mycustom module already has list.
i want to filter the data.